# Conditionally replace values in a subset of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Given the following data:

```py
dt = pd.DataFrame({"file": ["a", "a", "b", "b"], "val": [0, 1, 1, 2]})
```

which looks as

```
  file  val
0    a    0
1    a    1
2    b    1
3    b    2
```

I would like to repace `0` with `2` where `file == 'a'`.

The final result being:

```
  file  val
0    a    2
1    a    1
2    b    1
3    b    2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try

```
dt.loc[dt.file.eq('a')&dt.val.eq(0),'val']=2
dt
  file  val
0    a    2
1    a    1
2    b    1
3    b    2
```

Comment: thanks, this works, i was unsure about reassigning subsets of a dataframe.

Comment: Sorry - perhaps a new post, but is it possible to extend this to being able to carry out multiple replacements using `.replace` or something? Or, if there are multiple should it be done one after the other